# Is there any method for multiplying matrices having O(n) complexity?

Tags: c++, c, matrix, big-o

I want to multiply two matrices but the triple loop has O(n<sup>3</sup>) complexity. Is there any algorithm in dynamic programming to multiply two matrices with O(n) complexity?

ok fine we can't get best than O(n<sup>2.81</sup> )

**edit:** but is there any solution that can even approximate the result upto some specific no. of columns and rows of matrix

i mean we get the best of O(n<sup>2.81</sup> ) with a complex solution but perfect results but if there is any solution for even an approximation of multiplication of matrices as we have formulas for factorial approximation etc.

if there is any you know it will help me

regards.

Comment: `<sup></sup>` is your friend!

Comment: It's because you have not accepted a single answer to your 6 questions!

Comment: ok i have to choose an ans then how can i choose one?

Comment: can you multiply 2 numbers in O(n) time?

Comment: y r u asking this, its obvious we can do so.

Comment: Please try to use proper english to make it easy for others to understand you. "Why", not "y", "are", not "r", "you", not "u".

Are you really so lazy that those two extra characters per word cause you physical pain?

Comment: shortening an already short and concise language like English is insane.

Comment: elaborate your question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The **best** Matrix Multiplication Algorithm known so far is the **["Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm)** with  **O(n<sup>2.38</sup> )** complexity but it is *not* used for practical purposes.

However you can always use **["Strassen's algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)**  which has **O(n<sup>2.81</sup> )** complexity but there is no such known algorithm for matrix multiplication with O(n) complexity.

Comment: please note, that coppersmith has very high constant costs and therefore is only recommended for big matrices (forget about multiplying 2 4x4-matrices in a video game for example)

Comment: For each epsilon>0, there is an algorithm in O(2^{n+epsilon}). However, this is a theoretical result, the constant explodes when epsilon goes to zero?

Comment: Alexandre C. - +1 for optimism :)

Comment: @Alexandre: Is there actually a result to that effect that I'm not aware of?  I think basically everyone in the field believes that to be true, but I don't believe that anyone has succeeded in actually establishing it.

Comment: @Stephen: 1) it should be read O(n^{2 + epsilon}) 2) To be fair, I don't remember seeing it proven. I read about this bound a while ago, it wasn't surprising at the time, but you may be right if you say it is unproven. Nevertheless, the constant would explode with epsilon->0. What would be much more interesting is an algorithm in O(n^2 log^* n), like for multiplying polynomials.

Comment: @Alexandre: O(n^2 log n) is, I think, exactly what most people have in mind for such a O(n^{2 + eps}) algorithm (precisely because of the analogy to polynomial multiplication).  You might be thinking of Cohn et al.'s paper from 2005(?) that showed that there were O(n^{2 + eps}) algorithms *if* you could exhibit a family of algebraic structures with certain properties.  I don't think anyone has actually managed to prove their existence, however.

Answer (score 14):

There is a theoretical lower bound for matrix multiplication at O(n^2) as you have to touch that many memory locations to do the multiplication. As others have said, there are algorithms that drop us below O(n^3), but are usually impractical in real use.

If you need to speed it up, you might want to look at Cache Oblivious Algorithms, such as this one (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.5650) that accelerate performance by performing operations in a cache cohesive way, ensuring that data is in the cache when needed.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: No

Long answer: There are ways if you have special kinds of matricies (for instance a diagonal matrix). The better matrix multiplication algorithms out there can pare you down to something like O(n<sup>2.4</sup>) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith-Winograd_algorithm). The major one I am somewhat familiar with uses a divide and conquer algorithm to split up the workload (not the one I linked to).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Pah, I can't get the link to behave :(

Answer (score 2):

If the matrices are known to be diagonal, you can multiply them in `O(N)` operations.  But in general, you cannot.

Comment: or if they are Töplitz matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Matrices have O(n<sup>2</sup>) elements, and every element must be considered at least once for the result, so there is no possible way for a matrix multiplication algorithm to run in less than O(n<sup>2</sup>) operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `n²` processors and shared-read memory architecture, you could multiply two matrices in `O(n)` time... but this is only theory for now.

Answer (score 1):

If

- your matrices are large
- they have a lot of zeroes
- you are willing to store them in strange formats

you can devise algorithms whose complexities depend only on the number of non-zero elements. This can be mandatory for some problems (eg. finite element methods).

Answer (score 0):

No! I don't think so.

There is no way unless and until you are using a parallel processing machine. That too, it has its own dependencies and limitations.

Till now, its not yet achieved.

Comment: Parallel processing does not, in general, reduce the big-O complexity of algorithm.  There's always some fixed upper bound, say M, of your concurrency either from your parallel algorithm or hardware so you get at best a constant speedup.  (Not that constant speedups aren't good, mind you.)

Comment: You can only ever have up to a certain max number of processors, so parallel processing can only speed you up by some (possibly large) constant factor.

Comment: I know thats why I'd written 'it has its own dependencies'. 
I know a bit of Amdahl's law.
Thanks for the comment :-)