# Generating a sequence 1,3,8,22,60,164 .How to make my code more effficient?

Tags: c++, sequence

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#define REP(i,n) for (ll i = 1; i <= n; i++)
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long int ll;
typedef vector<vector<ll> > matrix;
ll MOD = 1000000007;
const ll K = 2;

// computes A * B
matrix mul(matrix A, matrix B)
{
    matrix C(K+1, vector<ll>(K+1));
    REP(i, K) REP(j, K) REP(k, K)
        C[i][j] = (C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j]) % MOD;
    return C;
}

// computes A ^ p
matrix pow(matrix A, ll p)
{
    if (p == 1)
        return A;
    if (p & 1)
        return mul(A, pow(A, p-1));
    matrix X = pow(A, p>>1);
    return mul(X, X);
}

// returns the N-th term of Fibonacci sequence
ll fib(ll N)
{
    // create vector F1
    vector<ll> F1(K+1);
    F1[1] = 1;
    F1[2] = 3;

    // create matrix T
    matrix T(K+1, vector<ll>(K+1));
    T[1][1] = 0, T[1][2] = 1;
    T[2][1] = 2, T[2][2] = 2;

    // raise T to the (N-1)th power
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    T = pow(T, N-1);

    // the answer is the first row of T . F1
    ll res = 0;
    REP(i, K)
        res = (res + ((T[1][i] )* (F1[i]))) %MOD;
    return res;
}
ll fib2(ll n)
{
    if(n==1)
    return 1;
    ll a=1;ll b=3;ll c;
    for(ll i=3;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=(2*a+2*b)%MOD;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    ll t;
    scanf("%llu",&t);
   // t=10000;
    ll n=1;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%llu",&n);
        //n=1;
       // n++;
     //  n=1000000000;
        printf("%llu\n",fib(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a code to generate 1,3,8,22,60,164 a[n]=2*(a[n-1]+a[n-2]) mod 10^9+7 .I am using modular exponentiation and the matrix multiplication method to generate this sequence.How can I improve its time from 2.3 seconds for worst case i.e. n=10^9 .
10000 times to around .5 to 1 second?
Please give me suggestions to improve speed of this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381277/how-to-speed-up-series-generation

Comment: @nhahtdh :I am using exponentiation b squaring

Comment: @Mysticial: If only that solved my problem I already using that technique

Comment: @Mysticial:please help I have spent 3-4 days on this problem.I tried out the characterstic equation generation,the matrix method,recursive method,the iterative method .Each and every thing.Now please gods like you need to help.I have tried hard enough

Comment: There are better algorithms for matrix multiplication that this. Look up any algorithms book for faster matrix multiplication. They are mainly based upon better math techniques

Comment: @fayyazkl :any suggestions..?

Comment: Look at following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1944648/67381

Comment: @Siddiqui: sir i am multiplying 2x2 matrices only

Comment: @Siddiqui: I have tried c[0][0]=a[0][0]*b[0][0]+a[0][1]*b[1][0]  this thing too..not even .1 second improvement.Time is nearly same

Comment: Throw away the `vector`. Try to see if you can reuse array instead.

Comment: but it is one hell of a trouble returning 2d arrays in c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `vector` is the main culprit here - dynamic allocation and numerical stuff don't mix very well.
2x2 matrices are way too small for any fancy algorithm to have any impact. I have a hunch that they'd actually be *worse* due to fanciness overhead.

Have you tried unrolling the loops and ditching the dynamic allocation?

I *hope* this is correct:

```
void mul(ll A[][2], ll B[][2], ll C[][2])
{
    C[0][0] = (A[0][0] * B[0][0]) % MOD;
    C[0][0] = (C[0][0] + A[0][1] * B[1][0]) % MOD;

    C[0][1] = (A[0][0] * B[0][1]) % MOD;
    C[0][1] = (C[0][1] + A[0][1] * B[1][1]) % MOD;

    C[1][0] = (A[1][0] * B[0][0]) % MOD;
    C[1][0] = (C[1][0] + A[1][1] * B[1][0]) % MOD;

    C[1][1] = (A[1][0] * B[0][1]) % MOD;
    C[1][1] = (C[1][1] + A[1][1] * B[1][1]) % MOD;
}

void pow(ll A[][2], ll p, ll out[][2])
{
    if (p == 1)
    {
        out[0][0] = A[0][0];
        out[0][1] = A[0][1];
        out[1][0] = A[1][0];
        out[1][1] = A[1][1];
        return;
    }
    if (p & 1)
    {
        ll B[2][2] = {{0}};
        pow(A, p - 1, B);
        mul(A, B, out);
    }
    else
    {
        ll X[2][2] = {{0}};
        pow(A, p >> 1, X);
        mul(X, X, out);
    }
}

ll fibv(ll N)
{
    ll T[2][2] =
    {
        {2, 2},
        {1, 0}
    };

    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    ll RM[2][2] = {{0}};
    pow(T, N-1, RM);
    ll res = RM[0][1] % MOD;
    res = (res + RM[0][0] * 3) % MOD;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry sir,I saw your post a bit late....I solved my problem with a hybrid of my code and the one you have written.Thanks sir, I will never use vector again in a time limit problem

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

You can even find it in video lectures at MIT Opencourseware Intro to Algorithms course or Stanford's Algorithms course

Comment: :I am multiplying only 2x2 matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a significant speedup if you specialise to 2x2 matrices:

```
struct matrix {
  ll a, b, c, d ;
  void Square() ;
  void Mul (const matrix& M) ;
  } ;
```