# Best way of constructing matrices in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I think there is no other discussion which answers precisely my question.

In C language I construct 2D arrays (with number of rows and coloumns possibly defined on the run) with pointers of pointers and dynamical memory allocation. Now in C++ I'm deciding if it is better to use standard vectors (of vectors) or continue to use pointers. I read that with standard vectors (of vectors) the memory for the components is not allocated sequentally. Is it true? If it is so this is enough for me to continue to use pointers for now, unless you give me some other definitely good reason not to do it.

The pointers I construct are the following (I didn't study classes yet):

```
template <typename T>
T **Mat(int r, int c)
{
    T** A = (T**)malloc(r * sizeof(T*));
    T* p = (T*)malloc(r * (c * sizeof(T)));
    if (p == NULL || A == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Memory not allocated";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++, p += c) A[i] = p;
    return A;
}

template <typename T>
void freeMat(T **A)
{
    free(A[0]); free(A);
}
```

Comment: I can't get you clearly. What do you mean "standard matrices"? In the STL, there is no class named matric.

Comment: I mean matrices constructed with standard vectors

Comment: Matrices are square, so use a flat array/vector not an array of arrays. Malloc/new the whole thing at once. Use modulo and division to index the matrix by row and column.

Comment: Please define what is the best way, better than what?

Comment: @JonnyHenly If I'm not wrong array of arrays is the only way to access matrix elements as A[i][j]

Comment: @D.Alfano `T* p = (T*)malloc(r * (c * sizeof(T)));` -- 1) This will fail if `T` is not trivially-copyable.  2) You failed to check for `NULL` being returned in the calls to `malloc`.  If you really and truly want to do anything looking like this in C++, [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can overload *get* (`[]`) operators in c++, which would allow you to take the `i` and `j` indexes and perform modulo and division arithmetic on them to transform the 2D index into a 1D index.

Comment: @273K The question I ask is in the post: "Is it true?". And I ask if there are other definitely good reasons to use std::vector

Comment: Use `class Matrix { ... T* operator[](size_t i) { return &vec[i * c]; } ... };`

Comment: even if you insist on pointers, don't do 2D pointers, try do something like [mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan). If you care about vector not being continuous you probably would also care 2D arrays may not be perfectly padded.

Comment: If I answer "yes, it's true", will you accept such answer? If not, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: `#include <string> ... int main() { std::string **s = Mat<std::string>(10,10); }` -- That will fail due to `malloc` not actually constructing `std::string` objects.  Also, your edited code still leaks memory if the second allocation fails, and the first allocation is successful.  Also, in my initial comment I stated "really and truly", since there are more efficient ways to do this.  However if you insist on using "pointers to pointers", at least it should be similar to the code I linked to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It was a typo. I corrected the code. However I don't understand what you mean in point 1). You told me in another discussion that if T is some class type this construction will fail. But what if I don't want to use classes at all?

Comment: @D.Alfano You created a template function.  That means that you, me, or anyone else can call your `Mat` function with anything we please -- that's the responsibility you take when you write such functions.  So you need to put constraints on the type that can be sent at compile-time, and that can be done using concepts, or if not that `std::enable_if`.  If you look at the sample I linked to, it doesn't have such issues due to using the proper allocation constructs (i.e. `new[]` and `delete[]`).

Comment: I'm a little confused at this point. I don't want to insist on pointers to pointers at all costs. I only care of the run time, so I thinked that was a good way to access matrix elements. Which is a better way?

Comment: That template is there just to chose between double or long double or complex numbers. It was not expected to be used with strings... but I understand the problem

Comment: @D.Alfano Change the allocations to `new[]` instead of `malloc`.  Then it doesn't matter what the type is.  You shoudn't have been using `malloc` anyway -- the usage of `malloc` in a C++ program should be very limited, if used at all.

Comment: A solution has already been suggested -- create a class template for your matrix, put a vector in it with enough storage for all the data, also store the number of columns (and rows, for good measure) in a member variable. Define an operator overload that returns a pointer into your storage which acts as the row selector. Now you have a very simple type that works like a 2D array but isn't. If you want to force it to only be valid for some types, that's also possible, but that would be more strict than your current example which does not care what type you use.

Comment: As to restricting the types, your template class would be using the facilities that [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) gives you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I'll read the usage of new[] (it's new for me) and try to adjust the code accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @paddy Classes are just what I wanted to avoid. I understand that I can create a single array and access its elements as A[i][j] simply acting on the indexes i and j. Is there a way to do so without classes?

Comment: You mean only making a single allocation instead of two allocations to produce an array of row pointers? Yeah it's possible but it's nasty. And you'd want to encapsulate that in a class because otherwise you'll have type punning issues. And you have to worry about memory alignment. If you're not ready for using classes (_a.k.a_ a `struct`), then there's no way you should be attempting a solution like this. I suggest that if you want to write C++, then _write C++_. Don't muck around trying to avoid language features. All you'll be doing is learning bad habits.

Comment: @paddy Ok, you're right. I'll learn classes. However I want to learn also C, so I'm still looking for the optimal way of defining matrices (for what concern execution time). And if I understood correctly this way is to define a single array

Comment: You have no choice if the matrix dimensions are not known at compile time. In C, you can use variable-length arrays (VLAs), but their usage is generally frowned upon. C++ does not support VLAs. So, in C++ if you want a 2D-addressable array stored contiguously in memory, then you need to allocate that block of memory. Your C code for this is creating two arrays. In C++, if you define your own type (a class) that manages this block of memory, then you don't need the row array. Instead, you can overload `operator[](size_t)` for your type. What might be good in C isn't necessarily good in C++.

Comment: Notice how your question has actually solicited a whole lot of back-and-forwards discussion, and the comments section is now a complete mess. This is the result of asking for "the best way". It's not answerable, or the answer is: it depends. So you don't really get answers. You'll find tons of examples of other questions about dynamic "2D" arrays here on Stack Overflow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you have not taken C++ classes yet, I can suggest a simple matrix template. Not sure I would use it as is in production code but it should get you started:

- It uses a single vector making it faster than having a vector of vectors in most (all?) cases.
- Items in the matrix can be access with the usual double `[]` operator: `matrix[row][column]`.
- The operators `+`, `-`, `*` have been overloaded  so that you can write e.g. `sum = matrix1 + matrix2`.
  Note that the multiplication is O(n<sup>3</sup>), I leave it to you to implement divide-and-conquer algorithms.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(size_t rowCount, size_t colCount) : rows(rowCount), columns(colCount), data(rowCount * colCount) {}

    T* operator[](size_t r) {
        return T*(&data[r * columns]);
    }
    void print(std::ostream& stream) {
        for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            for (size_t c = 0; c < columns; ++c)
                stream << (*this)[r][c];
            stream << '\n';
        }
    }


    template <typename T> friend
        Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<T>& b) {
        if (a.rows != b.rows || a.columns != b.columns)
            throw std::runtime_error("Matrices must have the same dimensions.");
        
        Matrix<T> result(a.rows, a.columns);
        auto o1 = a.data.cbegin(), o2 = b.data.cbegin();
        for (auto r = result.data.begin(); r != result.data.end(); ++r, ++o1, ++o2)
            *r = *o1 + *o2;
        return result;
    }
    template<typename T> friend
        Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<T>& b) {
        if (a.rows != b.rows || a.columns != b.columns)
            throw std::runtime_error("Matrices must have the same dimensions.");

        Matrix<T> result(a.rows, a.columns);
        auto o1 = a.data.cbegin(), o2 = b.data.cbegin();
        for (auto r = result.data.begin(); r != result.data.end(); ++r, ++o1, ++o2)
            *r = *o1 - *o2;
        return result;
    }

    template <typename T> friend
        Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<T>& b) {
        if (a.columns != b.rows)
            throw std::runtime_error("Matrices must have matching dimensions to be multiplied to each other.");

        Matrix<T> result(a.rows, b.columns);
        for (int r = 0; r < a.rows; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < b.columns; ++c) {
                T sum(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < a.columns; ++i) {
                    sum += a[r][i] * b[i][c];
                }
                result[r][c] = sum;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
private:
    size_t rows, columns;
    std::vector<T>data;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
Matrix<double> identity(3,3);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    identity[i][i] = 1.;
// Insert more code here
```

Comment: `const_cast` -- really??

Comment: Well, there a disclaimer for a reason. Too much of a shortcut, still?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to understand the particular (I understand in general). I'll have to study the usage of classes however

Comment: Is there a way to multiply 2 matrices in less than O(n^3) operations?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944621/is-there-any-method-for-multiplying-matrices-having-on-complexity

Comment: Of course. The current best method according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) is n^(2.3728596+o(1)). The corresponding algorithm is slower than regular O(n^3) multiplication except for huge matrices. Full optimization requires several algorithms to be implemented, each being suitable for increasingly big matrices (Wikipedia orders algorithms by efficiency which coincidently is how big a matrix they require to be worth it). I believe once you implemented the 2nd or 3rd of these, the required size becomes too big for present day computers.

Comment: One thing I have not mentioned is that this sort of things is why you generally want to have a class, contrary to your earlier comments. You can change how a class works internally (here, optimize a calculation) without having to change any of the code that uses said class.